# Age of a person going to space

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, inertial-frames, observers

When a person goes into space and stays there for a specific time without moving the spacecraft, will he age faster than those on earth?

Comment: Revrite as well-evalvated question obut physics. I assume that you are interested in relativistic effect? In case of classical physics, the time is allways the same everywhere.

Comment: Are you wanting to consider general relativity effects? And where in space? Without moving the spacecraft relative to what, Earth? Which Lagrangian point?

Answer (score 2):

As all motion is relative, I assume you mean the astronaut is not moving relative to the Earth. Gravity and relative motion can affect time dilation. So time will run a little slower on the surface of Earth, due to its gravity, than it will for the astronaut further from the surface.